# Synthetic Aperture Radar data format

Tags: sar

I'm trying to learn about the SAR image formation process.  From reference such as Carrara's Spotlight Synthetic Aperture Radar book, it appears that after various compensations, a direct 2D fft can be applied to 'compress' the data.

I understand range is in 'slow time', and crossrange/azimuth is in 'fast time'. 
 However, wouldn't applying the 2D fft directly result in the frequency domain? 
 What are the units in range/crossrange for raw, unfocused SAR data that allow us to directly apply a 2D fft to get a 'compressed' image (I believe this would result in a single look complex image?).

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! I see 4 questions in your post. The guidelines are for one focused question.

Comment: Sorry, I will chop it down to one.